# Why does thenCallRealMethod() lose the arguments here?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have the following code:

```
when(mockedOperation.getResult(anyDouble(), anyDouble())).thenCallRealMethod();
when(mockedOperation.division(anyDouble(), not(eq(0d)))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Where `Operation` is something like `Command` pattern - it encapsulates some concrete action, in this case, simplified - division operation. The result retrieval happens not directly, but by the means of contract method, say `getResult(arg1, arg2)`. So, I call

```
  mockedOperation.division(10d, 3d);
```

But (from debugging info in my concrete implementation of `Operation`) I can see that `division()` gets not `10` and `3` but `(0, 0)`.

As far as I understand, that arguments are lost somewhere between the `thenCallRealMethod()` by `getResult()` and calling *real* `division()` afterwards.

What is the reason for that behavior and how should I implement partial mocks correctly in case I really need it?

UPD. Maybe I should try to say it another way, for example, simply how do you create mocks that `callRealMethod` in such a way that arguments are correctly delivered to the endpoint?

Comment: Just wondering, would a `spy` help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the problem is solved now. Turns out I just encountered another undocumented feature/bug in Mockito (or just the feature I didn't find the docs for yet). The problem was that in my `@Before` I also mocked that very operation, and, as it appears, when one redefines mock, something black-magical happens and the result is as I've already  described - arguments are somehow lost.

Comment: My resolution was to change the order of statements. Initially, I had the `when(...)` calls before the `PowerMockito.mockStatic(...)` call. After I've put the `mockStatic(...)` before the `when(...)`-calls, it worked. Legit!